# How can I permanently set an environment variable using Autotools?

Tags: unix, environment-variables, autotools, autoconf, automake

I'm adapting an existing program to use Autotools for its build, but the resulting process depends on an environment variable. Is there a way to permanently set this environment variable during the build or installation process?

The program is intended to be used by Unix users and I could try to concatenate an export command directly to the .bashrc file and warn the user in case it fails because most of them will actually just use Ubuntu to run it (it's a relatively simple program that targets students), but I'd like to know if there's a more portable way to do this.

That's what I wouldn't like to do:

```
export VAR=/my/totally/not/hardcoded/path >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: Your question doesn't actually have anything to do with the build system. No build system lets you set an environment variable that is present when the program that it builds is run at some later time.

Comment: I would consider this 'capability' to be a massive security hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to come to this late, but all of the answers to date are shockingly ... incomplete.

Building and installing software are both core use cases for the Autotools, and the installation part can absolutely involve adding or modifying files that affect user environments.  If the software is installed by a user with sufficient privilege, then such effects can absolutely be applied to all system users, though the details may vary a bit from system to system (and the Autotools can help with that, too!).

For example, on RedHat-family Linuxes such as RedHat Enterprise, Fedora, Oracle Linux, and various others, you can drop an appropriately named file in `/etc/profile.d`, and the commands in it will automatically be read and executed by every login shell.  Setting environment variables for all users is one of the common uses of this feature.  I'm uncertain about Debian-family Linuxes such as Ubuntu, but it is always possible to modify file `/etc/profile` instead to have the same effect, and you absolutely can write an Automake install hook to do that.

Or for an altogether different approach, you can always provide a wrapper script around your program that sets the needed environment variables (supposing that the point is other than to add a directory to the `PATH` so as to find the program in the first place).  In that case, you can even install the main program in a location that is not ordinarily in the path, so that users don't accidentally run it directly.  This mechanism has the advantage that the environment variables are scoped to a run of the program, not a whole login session, but the disadvantage that users cannot override them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Do you think editing /etc/profile file would be a last resort?

Comment: I would absolutely consider editing `/etc/profile` to be a last resort.  Avoid that option if at all possible.  It is much better for your software to be responsible only for whole files, not sections of files.  And although I do not know whether Ubuntu honors `/etc/profile.d/*` files the same way the RedHat-family and some other distros do, I would be shocked to find that it didn't have at least a similar mechanism.  Also, do not neglect the wrapper option -- if it supports your needs, then it is probably the cleanest and most portable alternative available.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, no.

Autotools are about building your program, not about environment setup for the program to run. That's what users/admins are supposed to do. (Well I can *imagine* doing this, but I really don't want to try to figure it out, because the idea itself seems broken to me)

If your program REALLY needs some environment variable during run-time, then you should patch your sources for your application to test if the variable exists, and set one to default desired value, if it doesn't. Another idea is to enforce usage of an obligatory command line switch to pass the value in.

Comment: On the contrary, the Autotools are about both building *and installing* software.  The installation part absolutely can involve dropping or modifying environment-configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what this has to do with autotools (or any other build system). No build system, by itself, can arrange for an env var to be present when the program it builds is run at a later tiem.

One solution is for your program to have a hardcoded default value for the var which is used if the environment var isn't present when the program starts running. Another frequently used solution is to name your binary something like *myprog.bin* and install a shell script named *myprog* which sets up the environment before doing `exec myprog.bin`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm adapting an existing program to use Autotools for its build, but the resulting process depends on an environment variable. Is there a way to permanently set this environment variable during the build or installation process?

You've not been very concrete about what the program is (e.g. is the program a daemon?  A user program?) or the nature of the environment variable dependency (e.g. is it another program?  A mount point?  A URL? A DB connection string?).  Being more specific might give a better answer for you.

Anyway, autotools is not likely to offer any feature to help:  It's a build system.  Depending on the nature of your environment variable dependency, you're likely going to need package management (if you package it) or system administration level setup.

Since you think your primary user base is on Ubuntu [this help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables) might give you some ideas.